# Alfresco 4.0+ CMIS URL syntax

Tags: url, alfresco, cmis

I'm converting URL syntax from 3.4 to 4.2 syntax (CMIS 1.0)

I'm trying to upload a new version of a document to the PWC via a PUT for a document.

Previous 3.X syntax to upload to the PWC was as follows:

```
/alfresco/service/cmis/pwc/i/{id}?checkinComment={checkinComment?}&major={major?}&checkin={checkin?}
```

In 4.2 I am using this URL:

```
/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom/content?id=2e9c6773-4b02-41e0-b8e5-ce04a48c44f6?checkinComment=hgfhfgh&checkin=true&major=true
```

Here 2e9c6773-4b02-41e0-b8e5-ce04a48c44f6 == ID of the PWC.

I'm getting the error:
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I step through cmislib's checkIn unit test against a preview build of 4.2 Enterprise using the new service URLs, I see that the PUT that does the checkin is hitting this URL:

```
u'http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom/entry?id=71be4c86-1dcb-49a8-8373-d1c5ea4405b7%3Bpwc'
```

So try changing "content" to "entry" and also double-check that you have the ID of the PWC. Note that mine actually has "pwc" on the end whereas yours does not.

Comment: Thanks -- that got me further -- but I'm still puzzled.  I still see a 404 error when the comment and major/minor flag is included on the URL: checkinComment=hgfhfgh&checkin=true&major=true.  When those parameters aren't there it returns to me the AtomPub feed for the PWC node with no error, the original document is still checked out, and I don't see that the PWC content has changed.  I am doing a PUT.

Comment: I notice in your original post you have ?id= and then ?checkinComment which is incorrect. You should have ?id=XXXXXX&checkinComment=foo&checkin=true&major=true